# How to use Jsoup to get web content from an API

Tags: android, json, api, android-studio, jsoup

I have an API which response is in `JSON`, i need to get some content from it and one of them is an `url` from various news site. I hoped to get the individual paragraphs from the various news website (url) but i am having difficult, as passing the `url` from the `JSON` to the `Jsoup` as `string` aint working.

I tried using other `url` and i notice they don't work example: using `www.google.com` won't work, but adding `https://` to `www.google.com` works.

please does any have an idea on how to solve this error.

```
package wami.ikechukwu.kanu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class news_detail extends AppCompatActivity {

    //TODO: REMOVE THESE LINE IF THERE IS NO NEED FOR THEM IN THE APP
    // private final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
    private final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    //private final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private final String KEY_URL = "url";
    private final String KEY_URL_TO_IMAGE = "urlToImage";
    private final String KEY_PUBLISHED_AT = "publishedAt";
    int itemPosition;
    //this string is appended to the url
    String urlLink = "buhari";
    String url;
    TextView newsDetail_Title, newDetail_Time_Posted, newsDetail_News;
    ImageView newsDetail_Image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_detail);

        itemPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("POSITION", 0);

        newsDetail_Title = findViewById(R.id.newsDetail_Title);
        newDetail_Time_Posted = findViewById(R.id.newDetail_Time_Posted);
        newsDetail_News = findViewById(R.id.newsDetail_News);
        newsDetail_Image = findViewById(R.id.newsDetail_Image);

        newsRequest();
    }

    public void newsRequest() {

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=" + urlLink + "&language=en&sortBy=publishedAt&pageSize=100&apiKey=a5f976b34089493abc8f97f088e5df64", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("articles");

                    //Using a for loop to get the object (data) in the JSON
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(itemPosition);

                    newsDetail_Title.setText(jsonObject.getString(KEY_TITLE));
                    url = jsonObject.getString(KEY_URL);
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(jsonObject.getString(KEY_URL_TO_IMAGE)).into(newsDetail_Image);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String title;

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                    Elements element = document.select("p");
                    for (Element paragraph : element) {
                        builder.append(paragraph.text());
                    }

                    // title = document.title();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        newsDetail_News.setText(builder.toString());
                        // newsDetail_News.setText(title);

                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Jsoup would throw exception is url don't contain http or https.

Try this (in Kotlin) , you can convert code to java as well

```
previewUrl = if (!url.contains("http")) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
                    "https://$url"
                else {
                    "http://$url"
                }
            } else {
                url
            }
```

Comment: could you please explain what this code does so that i can manually convert it to java.

Comment: This code basically check if url contain http or not.
If it don't contain http in url then it add http or https before url based on Android version P. because on P above it supports https calls only.

If it contain http then use it directly.

Comment: Try handling redirection and timeout exceptions

document= Jsoup.connect(previewUrl).followRedirects(true).timeout(TIMEOUT_MILLIS).get()

Comment: thanks, what could possibly be the java equivalent of `"https://$url"`. i dont know kotlin.

Comment: String newUrl;
        if(!url.contains("http")){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
                newUrl = "https"+ url;
            }else {
                newUrl = "http"+ url;
            }

        }else{
                newUrl = url;
        }

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate your help. But the app keeps crashing, i discover that since i am running the Jsoup on a background thread, it doesn't get the latest data from the onCreate

Comment: please check you mail